# Angular 7: component doesn't reload on subsequent visits

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm converting an Angular 6 project to Ionic Framework with Angular 7.  So far, everything seems to be working fine, but I'm seeing a difference in behavior when I navigate to a route more than once.

In my Angular 6 project, the component will reload and run `OnInit` again (which gets fresh data from the back end), whereas in my new Angular 7, it does not, so data doesn't get refreshed.

My controller code is identical.

**What could explain the difference in behavior?**

Perhaps I've unintentionally configured something different between these two projects.

```
export class Messages implements OnInit {
    public threads;

    constructor(public nav: NavController,
                public utils: UtilsService,
                private api: ApiService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadThreads();
    }

    private loadThreads() {
        this.api.getThreads().subscribe(
            (response: ApiResponse) => {
                console.log('SUCCESS: Threads retrieved: ', response.data);
                this.threads = response.data;
            },
            (error) => {
                console.error('An error occurred making the request: ' + error.message);
                this.utils.displayToastMessage('Unable to retrieve your message threads.');
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Versions:

- Old Angular 6.1.4
- New Angular 7.2.6

Comment: What is the template code when it's used, how is this component used?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you are using your component in your new project, but basically a new component manually injected in the DOM or injected by router should trigger the ngOnInit() method.

You can see a quick example in the [Stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gkxarr) that demonstrate the manually injection of the **FixedComponent** by using  and the **DynamicComponent** injected by the Router. Open the console log and you will see after view seconds that the **FixedComponent** **ngOnDestroy**() and **ngOnInit**() methods will be called and log a message in the Stackblitz console. Same results if you navigate on the link and you go back to the homepage.

Angular component Lifecycle don't change between the version 6 and 7, you can refer to [this link](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) to see all component hooks and the component lifecycle mecanic.

Can you show us how "Message" is used or included in your project ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  You pointed me in the right direction with your comment about the lifcycle not changing between 6 and 7.  I've found out the problem is on the ionic side of things.  It provides it own `<ion-router-outlet>` that seems to be caching components. 

I'll be looking into that.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53395620/ionic-4-angular-6-how-to-control-ionic-router-history-to-stop-cache-a-view-co?rq=1

Comment: I did not read entirely the medium post, but I think it could may help you : https://medium.com/@paulstelzer/ionic-4-and-the-lifecycle-hooks-4fe9eabb2864

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the component was changed instead of recreated. So you'll need to use ngOnChanges.

You can see the docs for conponent lifecycle here - https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks